# how to run a django-upgrade command to whole django project?

Tags: python, django

I am using a library django-upgrade to convert the code from django 1.11 to django 3.24

the command is like

> django-upgrade --target-version 3.2 example/core/models.py

I want to know that how can I run this command so that it runs on whole django project.

Comment: instead of passing a path, have you tried the current folder with `.` ?

Comment: yes but it checks only current directory. I want it to check all the subdirectories and apply the command on python file

Answer (score 0):

I am clear on the question but if you are asking how to upgrade Django then in your virtual environment run pip `sudo pip install --upgrade django==3.2`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way with the library itself, since it takes file as argument. I did workaround for whole project with bash.
`for file_path in $(find . -name \*.py); do django-upgrade --target-version 3.2  "$file_path"; done`